# How can I accept (and parse) www-url-encoded data in a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redux, form-data

I am sending from a JS app:

```
let config = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  body: `email=${creds.email}&password=${creds.password}`
}
fetch('http://localhost:3000/sessions', config)
```

In my Rails controller:

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.where(email: params[:email]) # this doesn't work!
  end
end
```

I am getting a 400 bad request with:

```
Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 23:56:56 +0200
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

email=hello&password=moto

ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError
(743: unexpected token at 'email=hello&password=moto'):
```

Anybody could shine some light as to how to handle this data from JS?

Comment: It’s hard to tell what might be going on because the JS code in the question does not seem to be the same JS code that’s causing the problem shown in the log message in the question. The log message shows the log for a POST to the `/sessions` route, but your JS code shows a POST to `/sessions/create`. Also the log message shows it’s receiving `email=hello&password=moto`, but your JS code is for a POST that sends parameters in the form `username=hello&password=moto`.

Comment: Given that the JS code shown in the question doesn’t match the details of the server-side log message shown,  probably want to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45890012/edit to edit/update your question and post the actual exact JS code you’re testing the request with, and the actual exact log message you get on the server side when the server receives that request.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Sorry! You are right. Bad copy-paste. I have now edited the question to match exactly what I am seeing here. It's a `POST` to `/sessions` and the data sent/received is `email=hello&password=moto`

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you should add CSRF token to bypass forgery protection and add this key-value to your headers:

```
'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf-token]").content
```

otherwise you could use bundled rails-ujs library, which already has this token included:

```
Rails.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: "http://localhost:3000/sessions/create",
  data: mydata,
  success: function(repsonse){...},
  error: function(repsonse){...}
})
```

Comment: thanks! What exactly is `csrf-token` meta tag supposed to contain? My front-end is completely detached, so looks like I'll have to put it into my html by hand.

Comment: csrf-token is generated by Rails on request and then Rails is comparing all non-GET Ajax requests against it. You could completely disable forgery protection in controller, but I think it is not a great idea. Maybe you can pass `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` to your front-end and then use it in your Ajax requests? Here is the documentation, where I am getting it from:  [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures)

Comment: OK, it works now. But the question remains open. I have changed my headers to contain this instead: `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` and the body to contain: `{"email":"${creds.email}","password":"${creds.password}"}`. This (together with the fact that Rails API have no `csrf protection`) leads me to think that it's something else that is stopping me from encoding it in a form. Although, is it possible that only certain (form) POST requests have that protection turned on by default and others (regular POST requests) don't? :|

Comment: @Claudio Yes, you can specify for specific action to protect. POSTED

Comment: @7urkm3n What I am saying is that this works fine with json. So, it must be something else other than CSRF. CSRF is OFF. This is a Rails API with no csrf protection. Sending data in json format works. I'd like to know why it doesn't work in other formats.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify for specific action for csrf protect. -> [DOC](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: :create

  def create
    render plain: params
  end
end
```